# Is there a counterpart to Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, properties

Given is the following exemplary class structure:

```js
class matter {
  constructor(atomicNumber) {
    this.atomicNumber = atomicNumber;
  }
}

class stone extends matter {
  constructor(atomicNumber, mohsHardness) {
    super(atomicNumber);
    this.mohsHardness = mohsHardness;
  }

  showProperties() {
    console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this));
  }
}

class gem extends stone {
  constructor(atomicNumber, mohsHardness, carat) {
    super(atomicNumber, mohsHardness);
    this.carat = carat;
  }
}

let chunk = new gem(6, 10, 1);
chunk.showProperties();
```

The output of function `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` is, as expected,

```js
['atomicNumber', 'mohsHardness', 'carat']
```

How do I get only the properties of the "parent" classes, as there would be

```
['atomicNumber', 'mohsHardness']
```

If I replace the function like this:

```
showProperties() {
    const parentClass = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this));
    console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(parentClass));
}
```

I get the result

```
['constructor', 'showProperties']
```

That leaves me at a loss. Maybe there is a counterpart to Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty?

Comment: Everything you assign with `this.` is "own" by definition. A non-own property is something shared by all instances of a class, e.g. a method.

Comment: All your properties are on the same object.  They don't "belong" to any particular class.  They belong to an object.  All the classes can read and write them and they're all equally properties on the same `this` object.  Thus, there is no property that belongs to a specific class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when a child instance is created, the `this` referred in the `matter` and `stone` constructors is exactly the same object as the `this` referenced in the child constructor (the `gem`). After the child constructor changes the instance, there's no way to differentiate a property added by the child constructor from a property added by a super constructor.

The only way to do something like this would be to check the object after the `super` call is done, before the child constructor mutates the object:

```js
class matter {
    constructor(atomicNumber) {
        this.atomicNumber = atomicNumber;
    }
}

class stone extends matter {
    constructor(atomicNumber, mohsHardness) {
        super(atomicNumber);
        this.mohsHardness = mohsHardness;
    }

    showProperties() {
        console.log(this.parentProperties);
    }
}

class gem extends stone {
    constructor(atomicNumber, mohsHardness, carat) {
        super(atomicNumber, mohsHardness);
        this.parentProperties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this);
        this.carat = carat;
    }
}

let chunk = new gem(6, 10, 1);
chunk.showProperties();
```

Comment: »there's no way to differentiate a property added by the child constructor from a property added by a super constructor« - I take this as an answer. Thank you.